# IIS 7 URL Rewrite for 404 and Sitefinity

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, sitefinity

We have a new Sitefinity site that is replacing our marketing site. The switchover happened last friday, and we uncovered a problem today: there is content (pdfs, jpgs) on the old site that can no longer be accessed, and did not make it into the content migration plan. On top of that, management has removed rollback as an option.

So, the solution I have come up with is to use IIS 7's url rewriting module to point to a new url that hosts the old site so that content can be accessed. This is the xml in my web.config that I have come up with:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RedirectFileNotFound" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />                    
                    <add input="{URL}" negate="false" pattern="/\.*$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.oldsite.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

It attempts to test if the URL resolves to a file or folder, and makes sure that we are requesting something with an extension. If the rules pass, it redirects to the same location on the old site. Ideally, this would mean that anything linking to the old site previously would be able to be left alone.

The problem is, nothing gets redirected.

By fiddling with the rules, I have verified that the module is operational, i.e. i can set it up to rewrite everything, and it works. but these rules do not work.

My theory is that since Sitefinity uses database storage, it somehow short circuits the "IsFile" match type. Complete guess, but I'm kind of at a loss at this point.

How to I use urlrewriting to redirect for 404's in this manner?

Comment: What is the last condition on {URL} for?

Comment: Mtaching requests that have extensions. Sitefinity uses rewriting that results in names like www.site.com/page, and the last check assumes that all of those are ok, and doesnt try to redirect them. It is, however unneccesary for the problem i am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help, but it turned out to be a problem with Dynamic Served Content in general.

Assume that all requests are actually handled by a Default.aspx page. This isn't the way that Sitefinity works, but it is the way that DotNetNuke works, and illustrates the problem nicely.

The url rewrite isfile and isdirectory flags check for physical existence of files. In this case, only Default.aspx actually physically exists. All the other dynamically served content is generated later in the request cycle, and has no physical existence whatsoever.

Because of that, the isfile flag will always fail, and the redirect rule will always execute.

The solution I went with was to allow IIS and .NET to handle the 404s themselves, which properly respects generated content. and route that to a custom error page, 404redirection.aspx. There is code on that page that redirects to my old site, where that content is likely to be host. That site then has additional 404 handling that routes back to the 404NotFound.aspx page, so requests for files that don't exist in either system make a round trip and look like they never went anywhere. This also has the nice side effect of pages that aren't found on the old server get to display our new, pretty, rebranded 404 on the new server.

Simply put, rather than attempting to pre-empt the content generation and error handing, I took a more "go with the flow" approach, and then diverted the flow at a more opportune time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the rewriter is implemented, but those rules seem to be too general. Sitefinity uses the routing engine and registers a series of routes that it handles. By definition, those routes are interpreted sequentially, so if a more general rule exists before a more specific one, the latter will not work.

I suspect what may be happening is that the Sitefinity rules already handle the request before the rewriter gets a chance to redirect it. What I can advise is to either implement more specific rewrite/redirect rules, or just handle the whole issue using a different approach. What was the reason your old files were inaccessible after the migration? Can you give a specific URL that fails to return the file, so we can work with a scenario?

Comment: Actually, the problem is the opposite. The URLRewriter executes before the router, so any Sitefinity generated content doesn't exist, and technically never will in a physical sense anyway

Answer (score 0):

this is just a shot in the dark, but do you have "file system fallback" enabled in the sitefinity advanced settings for libraries? perhaps the module is intercepting the request and not letting it proceeed to the file-system...

Comment: this would work for content libraries, since right now its all DB storage, but its not just images and files - any request for a page would technically still not exist.